# linux + from lsblk partitions size are greater then disk size

Tags: linux, lvm, disk-usage, lsblk

I get the following details from RHEL 7.2 machine , sda DISK is using LVM

```
lsblk
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda 8:0 0 250G 0 disk
├─sda1 8:1 0 500M 0 part /boot
├─sda2 8:2 0 199.5G 0 part
│ ├─vg-cluster-lv_root 253:0 0 183G 0 lvm /
│ ├─vg-cluster-lv_swap 253:1 0 16G 0 lvm [SWAP]
│ └─vg-cluster-lv_var 253:2 0 100G 0 lvm /var
└─sda3 8:3 0 50G 0 part
└─vg-cluster-lv_root 253:0 0 183G 0 lvm /
sde 8:64 0 50G 0 disk
└─sde1 8:65 0 50G 0 part
└─vg-cluster-lv_root 253:0 0 183G 0 lvm /
sr0 11:0 1 1024M 0 rom




df -h
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-cluster-lv_root 183G 69G 115G 38% /
devtmpfs 95G 0 95G 0% /dev
tmpfs 95G 96K 95G 1% /dev/shm
tmpfs 95G 4.1G 91G 5% /run
tmpfs 95G 0 95G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1 497M 158M 340M 32% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg-cluster-lv_var 100G 86G 15G 86% /var


blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda | awk '{ printf "%.2f\n", $1/1024/1024/1024; }'
250.00
```

as we can see above the size of the disk is `250g`

but on other hand we can see that root file system is `183g`

/dev/mapper/vg-cluster-lv_root 183G 69G 115G 38% /

and /var file system is `100g`

/dev/mapper/vg-cluster-lv_var 100G 86G 15G 86% /var

so how it can be ? ( `183+100 = 283` ) , while disk size is only `250g`

what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your VG `vg-cluster` has three PVs -- `/dev/sda2` (199.5G), `/dev/sda3` (50G), and `/dev/sde1` (50G) on the second disk, so you have approximately 300 GiB of space in the VG that is all used by your `lv_root`, `lv_swap` and `lv_var` LVs.

Note: When gathering information about storage when LVM is involved, using `lvs`/`pvs`/`vgs` is usually better than `lsblk` which cannot display detailed information about the LVM setup, it shows only basic information about block devices. And displaying devices with multiple "parents" (not only LVM but also MD RAID for example) is always a little confusing with `lsblk`. In this case you case `vg-cluster-lv_root` has three "parents" in the output.

Comment: I need to extend the /var by +100g , so do we need to add additional disk and use this disk + extend the VG + Extend the logical volume and finally extend the /var filesystem  ?

Comment: Yes. (You can do the LV + filesystem resize in one step with `lvresize --resizefs`.)

Comment: I prefer to do this --> pvcreate /dev/sdX   +  vgextend vg-cluster  /dev/sdX 
   + lvresize --size +100g /dev/mapper/vg-cluster-lv_var , and xfs_growfs /var      , is it ok  ?

Comment: In case anyone ever lands here like I did, trying to figure out the final step to extend VirtualBox drive capacity, I finished it up with `sudo xfs_growfs /dev/etc1/etc2`: After running `lvs`, I saw that my target drive had the "LSize" I expected, even though the Disk Usage Analyzer showed the actual size. From the `lvs` output, I then took the VG and LV column values for that drive, and used those in the place of "etc1" and "etc2" respectively. In the end, for my VirtualBox Red Hat guest system, my final command was `sudo xfs_growfs /dev/rhel/root`